# Accessing WeChat Web API

Tags: rest

Is there any way to download all of a user's messages or contacts using some sort of Web API? I have an account that is receiving a lot of messages, and I need to analyze these messages. It would be pretty painful to do it by hand, so a web API would be a real life saver.

Comment: Have you found your solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you mentioned about the WeChat official account, is possible to do that by using the developer server setting. When normal user send a message to the official account, wechat server will post a XML package to your preset URL, and you may store the data into your database for further analysis.
For more information, kindly look into this url: http://admin.wechat.com/wiki/index.php?title=Common_Messages

If you mentioned about normal user account, as i know that is impossible to download/capture the incomming message from Web API.